# dcmqrscp and echoscu only work with ANY

Tags: dcmtk

I'm using dcmtk 3.6.1 on Windows 8. I cannot access a PACS server using dcmqrscp and echoscu and the following dcmqrscp.cfg (error is Called AE Title is not recognised).

```
NetworkTCPPort  = 11112
MaxPDUSize      = 16384
MaxAssociations = 16

HostTable BEGIN
PACS1           = (PACS_SRC1, localhost, 11112)
PACSSRC         = PACS1
HostTable END

VendorTable BEGIN
"PACS source"       = PACSSRC
VendorTable END

AETable BEGIN
PACS_SRC       G:\develop\studyaccess\test\PACS_SRC      RW (100, 1024mb)   PACSSRC
AETable END
```

Commands:

```
dcmqrscp.exe -v -d --config dcmqrscp.cfg --propose-lossless 11112 > dcmqrscp.out

echoscu.exe -v -d localhost 11112 -aec PACS_SRC -aet echoscu

echoscu.exe -v -d localhost 11112 -aec PACS1 -aet echoscu
```

However, if I use ANY it does work:
    PACS_SRC       G:\develop\studyaccess\test\PACS_SRC      RW (100, 1024mb)   ANY

This indicates that the databases, paths and data are correct, but something else is wrong. I've turned Windows Firewall off.

I've also tried using dcmtk executables generated when compiling CTK (based on dcmtk), but they have the same result. CTK itself, works with C-GET but not with C-STORE (as part of C-MOVE).

Any other ideas?

Eddie

Answer (score 0):

Your two calls of the echoscu tool use "echoscu" as the Calling AE Title (-aet option). However, if you specify "PACSSRC" instead of "ANY" in the dcmqrscp.cfg file, this name is checked and not found to be valid for this "company". Your second call of echoscu (with option "-aec PACS1") will not work since "PACS1" is not specified as a known storage area in the "AETable" section of the config file.

See documentation file [dcmqrcnf.txt](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs-snapshot/file_dcmqrcnf.html) or [this](http://support.dcmtk.org/redmine/projects/dcmtk/wiki/Howto_PACSDebuggingWithDCMTK) HOWTO for details.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had already seen those links and checked them again. I don't see anything wrong with dcmqrscp.cfg above. I assumed from the help files that the -aet option was not checked. In any case, I expected this to work: `echoscu.exe -v -d localhost 11112 -aec PACSSRC -aet PACS_SRC1`, but it returns "Called AE Title is not recognised". I've also tried all combinations of -aec as PACSSRC and PACS_SRC, and -aet as PACS_SRC1, PACS1, PACSSRC and PACS_SRC, but with the same result.

Comment: Please re-read my above answer (and the referenced documentation if needed). PACSSRC is not a valid storage area but just a symbolic name that is mapped to the known host PACS1 (again a symbolic name), which has the AE title PACS_SRC1. The only storage area (and, therefore, supported called AE title) is PACS_SRC... So, `echoscu -v localhost 11112 -aec PACS_SRC -aet PACS_SRC1` should work. Maybe, it would be easier to use other names in your test environment :)